# Transcoder fails to write output due to permission issue

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

The transcode job is able to read the file but the output directory is not getting created.

I checked the log and the error is due to permission issue with Storage. I would like to get your help related to this issue.

Logs:

The response of the video transcoding is as follows.

```
 {
  "name": "projects/PROJECT-NUMBER/locations/us-central1/jobs/JOB-ID",
  "config": {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "key": "input0",
        "uri": "gs://input.mp4"
      }
    ],
    "editList": [
      {
        "key": "atom0",
        "inputs": [
          "input0"
        ],
        "startTimeOffset": "0s"
      }
    ],
    "elementaryStreams": [
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h264",
          "profile": "high",
          "preset": "veryfast",
          "heightPixels": 720,
          "widthPixels": 1280,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "bitrateBps": 1500000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "crfLevel": 21,
          "vbvSizeBits": 1500000,
          "vbvFullnessBits": 1350000,
          "gopDuration": "3s",
          "entropyCoder": "cabac",
          "frameRate": 60
        },
        "key": "video-streamR480P"
      },
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h264",
          "profile": "high",
          "preset": "veryfast",
          "heightPixels": 1080,
          "widthPixels": 1920,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "bitrateBps": 3000000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "crfLevel": 21,
          "vbvSizeBits": 3000000,
          "vbvFullnessBits": 2700000,
          "gopDuration": "3s",
          "entropyCoder": "cabac",
          "frameRate": 60
        },
        "key": "video-streamR720P"
      },
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h264",
          "profile": "high",
          "preset": "veryfast",
          "heightPixels": 1440,
          "widthPixels": 2560,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "bitrateBps": 6000000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "crfLevel": 21,
          "vbvSizeBits": 6000000,
          "vbvFullnessBits": 5400000,
          "gopDuration": "3s",
          "entropyCoder": "cabac",
          "frameRate": 60
        },
        "key": "video-streamR1080P"
      },
      {
        "videoStream": {
          "codec": "h264",
          "profile": "high",
          "preset": "veryfast",
          "heightPixels": 2160,
          "widthPixels": 3840,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "bitrateBps": 10000000,
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "crfLevel": 21,
          "vbvSizeBits": 10000000,
          "vbvFullnessBits": 9000000,
          "gopDuration": "3s",
          "entropyCoder": "cabac",
          "frameRate": 60
        },
        "key": "video-streamR1440P"
      },
      {
        "audioStream": {
          "codec": "aac",
          "bitrateBps": 512000,
          "channelCount": 2,
          "channelLayout": [
            "fl",
            "fr"
          ],
          "sampleRateHertz": 48000
        },
        "key": "audio-stream"
      }
    ],
    "muxStreams": [
      {
        "key": "mux-streamR480P",
        "fileName": "mux-streamR480P.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "video-streamR480P"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "mux-streamR720P",
        "fileName": "mux-streamR720P.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "video-streamR720P"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "mux-streamR1080P",
        "fileName": "mux-streamR1080P.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "video-streamR1080P"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "mux-streamR1440P",
        "fileName": "mux-streamR1440P.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "video-streamR1440P"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "mux-streamaudio-stream",
        "fileName": "mux-streamaudio-stream.m4s",
        "container": "fmp4",
        "elementaryStreams": [
          "audio-stream"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "manifests": [
      {
        "fileName": "manifest.mpd",
        "type": "DASH",
        "muxStreams": [
          "mux-streamR480P",
          "mux-streamR720P",
          "mux-streamR1080P",
          "mux-streamR1440P",
          "mux-streamaudio-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "fileName": "master.m3u8",
        "type": "HLS",
        "muxStreams": [
          "mux-streamR480P",
          "mux-streamR720P",
          "mux-streamR1080P",
          "mux-streamR1440P",
          "mux-streamaudio-stream"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "output": {
      "uri": "gs://output-bucket/"
    }
  },  "ttlAfterCompletionDays": 30
}
```

Job_ID is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the job and found the failure message:

Job validation failed: atom atom0 does not have any inputs (input0) with an audio track

It has nothing to do with storage permission. Can you fix the edit list with an input that includes audio track and try again?

I think the permission error that you observe is happening on the client side and is not related to the Transcoder API

Comment: Did you find any solution?